# Use RNFrostedSidebar as part of the UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So I found a very appealing pop-up sidebar animation on [Github](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNFrostedSidebar). However, I was only able to use it as a pop-up sidebar (like the screenshot below). I want to add it to my ViewController as a left side bar (like the second screenshot) but haven't found a way to do it. Any suggestion?
[image] 
[image]
Update: This is my viewDidLoad. I tried `[self.view addSubview:callout.contentView]` but it didn't work

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *images = @[
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Me.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Trends.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Setting"],
                        ];

    RNFrostedSidebar *callout = [[RNFrostedSidebar alloc] initWithImages:images];
    callout.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:callout.contentView];

    [callout show]; }
```

And this is the RNFrostedSidebar API

[RNFrostedSidebar.h](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNFrostedSidebar/blob/master/RNFrostedSidebar.h)
[RNFrostedSidebar.m](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNFrostedSidebar/blob/master/RNFrostedSidebar.m)

Comment: why cannot you add instance of RNFrostedsidebar to your uiview?

Comment: you create object for popover right follow the same procedure and add it to yourview

Comment: in frosted sidebar if you have any methods to display and hide just call display method in viewdidload and dont hide it

Comment: you have to add some constraints to adjust your uiview size width and you can play with frostedsidebar as menu

Comment: well I tried not to hide it but whenever I clicked outside the sidebar, the bar still goes away. I updated my code in the post, would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a simple UIView for that purposes? `RNFrostedSideBar` is too much custom solution for your need.

Just set enough auto layout constraints and change your `sideBar` outlet width-constraint constant value (animated). Take a look at [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), it'll help you.

I'll try to explain my vision of your UIViewController view contents

```
+-------------------------+
|sideBar|  contentView    |
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
+-------------------------+
 <--W-->
```

Where `W` is Width-layout constraint connected to your `@property (weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *sideWidthConstraint`. All other constraints for `sideBar` and `contentView` such as `Leading`,`Trailing`,`Top`,`Bottom` should set to zero. Pay attention at the constraints between the views. It must be zero too:

```
+---------------------------+
| sideBar |-0-| contentView |
```

When you need to change your `sideBar` width (and reduce one of `contentView`), just change `sideWidthConstraint` constant value:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
  self.sideWidthConstraint.constant = expanded ? 50 : 0; // expanded - YES of NO
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: I like the animation of the `RNFrostedSideBar` so I want to use it. Thanks a lot for your explanation though

Comment: No problem, find animation part from the `RNFrostedSideBar` and apply it to your bar items. It's much more simpler than accustom whole the solution. Good luck.